# Is there a Joomla plugin that will show/hide content after clicking?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, joomla

I want to install a plugin in Joomla which will give me the option to show/hide functionality after a click, maybe like most of the websites have FAQs (onclick of the question answer is shown).

```
Question 1 (click to see answer)
{
blah blah blah for question 1
}
Question 2 (click to see answer)
{
blah blah blah question 2
}
```

Comment: Well, start here: http://extensions.joomla.org/

Comment: Hi Damien, I don't know which plugin will work for me, cause I tried 3,4 plugins. so may be someone knows some other plugin that'll be get my work done or the simple coding logic, that'll also work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution from http://www.webconstruction.ch

version :- showhidecontent_1.1.7.zip (version 1.1.7)

thanks all for your response....

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using jQuery, you can try out this method:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Comment: yes, but how can we do it in joomla, I m looking for pre-made plugin to do that.

Answer (score 0):

[Sliders](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sliders) will do exactly what you want to do.  I have used this extension to do similar things.